# How can I insert column values in a particular row separately?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a table with columns {a, b, c} and for row x I want to add a value for a, then a value for b, then a value for c all in separate activities as the user progresses through my app (for another user, values for a, b, and c would be added separately to a row y). How can I do this?

Comment: i think you need to add a primary key to your table

{a,b,c,key}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a can be insert
and then b and c will have to be updates to the row

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to add a primary key to your table {a,b,c,key_column}

and then you can use below..

To update a:-

```
UPDATE table_name
SET a=valueA
WHERE key_colum=key_value;
```

To update b:-

```
UPDATE table_name
SET b=valueB
WHERE key_colum=key_value;
```

To update c:-

```
UPDATE table_name
SET c=valueC
WHERE key_colum=key_value;
```

Comment: Does it matter if this process is just going to be with the most recent row? It's a one shot process, so I was thinking I would just reference the last row and update that.

Comment: if you can select most recent row and update the same without a primary key, then no need of primary key...

Comment: OK great that's what I thought.

Comment: one help, Can you please tell me how you going to update the row without using primary key.

Comment: You're saying I can't do that? I'm not advanced so I don't know for sure.

Comment: you can update using ROWID,

long id = db.insert(//insert value 'a');//this will insert a and return rowid

then update table to insert b

UPDATE table_name
SET b=valueB
WHERE ROWID=id;

use the above for 'c' also..

it may work..

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html